# Errors are values (blog) - is logically same?

Tags: error-handling, exception, go

I just read the [blog](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) written by Rob Pike. I have a small question regarding this and may be I can be wrong too but would still like to get feedback and understand properly the Go.

In the blog there was a snippet code (which actually was written by @jxck_)

```
_, err = fd.Write(p0[a:b])
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err = fd.Write(p1[c:d])
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err = fd.Write(p2[e:f])
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// and so on
```

a) As per my understanding the above code will return if error occurred at `fd.Write(p0[a:b])`, and will never execute `fd.Write(p1[c:d])` , right?

And Rob suggested to write something like this

```
var err error
write := func(buf []byte) {
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    _, err = w.Write(buf)
}
write(p0[a:b])
write(p1[c:d])
write(p2[e:f])
// and so on
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

b) Based on the above, looks like the error will return from the sub function. So this means if the error occurs at `write(p0[a:b])` then still it will execute `write(p1[c:d])`, right? So this means logically both are not same, right?

Anybody explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Yes, you are correct. If the error occures in the first write, it will return.

b) No. The `write` in this example is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). The `err` inside of it is the same as in the outer scope. So if the first write fails, the other will simply return, because the outer `err` is not `nil` anymore.

Comment: Both versions are not strictly equivalent regarding the operations being executed, since the original version uses an early return in case of error whereas second one checks for nil as many times as the write closure is called.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are the same. If an `error` occurs at `fd.Write(p0[a:b])`, the `err` variable will hold its value.

Now if you call `write(p1[c:d])`, then the `write()` func will first check if `err != nil` but since it already stores the `error` which occured in the previous call, it will return immediately and will not execute further code.